# Why did my reputation drop by 6?

Tags: support, reputation

Just now, I was at 1408, then, suddenly, I saw that it had dropped down to 1402 with no notice in the reputation tab. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because you deleted [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/213186/31394).**

It had one upvote (+10 rep) and two downvotes (-4 rep), so deleting it cost you 6 rep.

Comment: That was it! Thanks very much!